# how to add a button in the [add to cart] side?

Tags: woocommerce

photo http://sleekupload.com/uploads/5/nb.png

How to write in functions.php

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: What do you want that button to do?

Answer (score 0):

The hook that you are looking for is woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button. To write a function, please review [WordPress Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). If this is too confusing, you have the option of editing the templates themselves by going to /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/ then you can do a search for woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button. Keep in mind that updating WooCommerce may erase those templates so I advice you to keep your template files in your theme instead.